How to build LLVM documentation on Linux?
I built all of llvm using the Build Clang on Unix-like System instructions.

That does not seem to include any man files for clang and the various tools.  Something that is available through the dnf package manager via the llvm-doc RPM.
The available package is for an older release (17.0.6-2 at this point). I want to use the latest and that's why I built llvm/clang from source.

I searched for instructions or make rules for creating documentation, man files, but I did not see anything.
Question: How does one build the clang/llvm documentation from source?

Hi, did you try the instructions provided here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/97743b8be86ab96afb26ba93e1876406c1f4d541/llvm/docs/README.txt#L30?

Not yet.  I will.  Thanks!

The key to this is to look for the various README and README.txt files inside the repo which explain the cmake commands required to create the proper make file for building the extra stuff.  The relevant file here is the llvm/docs/README.txt. I will go through that and will provide more info.  The repo has (at this point in time) 29 README files and 75 README.txt files.

Feel free to post the answer here (transposed from the docs) and mark it as accepted.  It's likely to help others!

I was able to build the LLVM docs.  Had to install Sphinx for that.  I also saw info to build a man page.  But I did not yet manage to build the docs for clang.  It's probably related to the CMake command.   I'll have to dig into that.  But I don't have the time for this extra digging at the moment.  I will do it, but I don't know when I'll have time for it yet...
